# Mysql search Question, extract most last date from two table

Tags: mysql, database, data-analysis

Say I have two tables a and b , b has an foreign key related on a

Table A  has

```
              | id | lastmodfied |
                 1   2022/10/21
```

Table B has

```
               |id | lastmodified |
                 1   2022/11/22
                 1   2022/12/31
```

I want to extract the most last date. How can I achieve this

Comment: Join the tables and use `MAX(lastmodified) GROUP BY id`

Comment: can you write a sample ? use left join?

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two tables with `UNION`, then use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT id, MAX(lastmodified)
FROM (
    SELECT id, lastmodified
    FROM tableA
    UNION 
    SELECT id, lastmodified
    FROM tableB
) AS x
GROUP BY id
```